# Angular material multi select get selected value on hide

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, multi-select

**Scenario :**

- I have a filter in angular material multi-select

**Todo :**

- I want to get the selected values on hide of dropdown..

  > I googled and tried to find the doc but could not found any ref to add
  >   hide event to miltiselect

Comment: can you please add more details on what you're trying to achieve? or include a stackblitz sample of your code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Demo where multi-select values are available after closed mat-select dropdown](https://angular-values-access-after-dropdown-close.stackblitz.io)

**Application Code :** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-values-access-after-dropdown-close?file=src/app/app.component.html

**Approach :**

- Keep a variable to store `multi-select` values.
  Use **`openedChange`** event as `(openedChange)="comboChange($event)"`, and in that store the selected values into an array or a different variable.
  Event value is `false` if dropdown is closed, so i have used it in the demo code.
- Also, `mat-select` is used with `[formControl]="toppings"`, so in any other method, you can access its value using **`this.toppings.value`**, it will return an array with selected values.

Comment: I want when dropdown hide, not when selection made

Comment: then you can use directly, as `this.toppings.value`, if done according `[formControl]="toppings"`, there are only 2 event emitters for `mat-select`, one is `openedChange`, and other is `selectionChange`, Use any to get the value.

Comment: Could you please update the link, I don't understand u, I want hide event to be fired

Comment: Give me a minute, i wil update the answer with other event emitter.

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam please check the updated demo code and answer.

Comment: please remove the link from the question, as it redirecting to updated code now, and not the `selectionChange` Event code.

Comment: Thanks, let me implement it

Comment: link was helpful to figure out a work around

Answer (score 0):

Adding Formcontrol variable like below we can enumerate the selected items from a angular multiselect dropdown

```
 <mat-select multiple placeholder="Reason" [formControl]="selectedReasons">
        <mat-option value="option1">option1</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="option2">option2</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="option3">option3</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="option4">option4</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
```

TS

```
 selectedReasons = new FormControl();

  reasonDropdownChangeEvent(event: any) {
console.log(this.selectedReasons.value.toString());
```

}